# Correct *scanf("%d",...) implementation, especially handling a string with a sign follwed by non-numbers, according to ANSI/ISO C?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to implement an esolang interpreter from scratch, in shell script and POSIX utilities. The original interpreter uses the function `scanf("%d",&i);` and I am trying to imitate how the C standard library does, completely.

I thought what the correct algorithm for `scanf("%d",&i);` or similar ones shall be, according to the C standards.

Many kinds of input can be assumed against the function, and I guess these are examples (the `?` on `i` stands for no changes, I think):

```
input            /returns/i     /next getchar() returns

"-1xxx"           1       -1    'x'
"WTF"             0       ?     'W'
"-++-"            0?      ??    first '+' or first '-'?
"-  3"            0?      ??    first ' ' or '-'?
```

I am not just sure what documents to refer.

The implementation I am thinking as of now, in AWK:

```
function get_integer( c,sign,digits){
   # assumes getchar() returns a digit of character codepoint; -1 for EOF
   # also assumes ungetc() can be done as many times as you want;
   # example
   #    ungetc(3); ungetc(4); c1=getchar(); c2=getchar(); c3=getchar();
   #    # c1==4, c2==3, c3 shall be actually next input
   for(;;){
      c=getchar();
      if(isblank(c)) continue;
      break;
   }
   sign=(c==43)-(c==45);
   if(sign!=0) c=getchar();
   if(sign==0&&!(48<=c&&c<=57)){
      if(strict_mode) abort();
      if(!strict_mode){
         # TBH I know against "   xyz"
         # Also "   +42" would not come here
         # BUT what about "   +hello"
         # also what about "   +   33 "
         ungetc(c);
         if(sign!=0) ungetc(44-sign); # TODO: should I delete this line?
         return 0;
      }
   }
   if(sign==0) sign=1;
   # and then I know I shall repeat reading numbers until non-numbers come
   # then: ungetc(first non-number);
   # and finally: return final result;
}
```

Clarification: I would just like to know what the official algorithm is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf("%d",&i);` first consumes leading whitespace: `isspace()`, not `isblank()`.  If next input is not a valid `int` text sequence.  at least 1 character is put back into `stdin`.  If more characters needs to be put back as in `"-+"`, it is UB or implementation defined.  If input outside `int` range, then UB (do whatever makes sense).  Input after numeric input is put back.

Comment: So, should `scanf("%d",&x)` should return 0, unchanging variable x, against the input "-  3", for example?

Comment: @tailsparkrabbitear Yes - should return 0.  The next character to be read is either `"-"` or `" "`.  Typically it is `"-"` (2 characters pushed back), but only 1 push-back is guaranteed.  `x` value is not updated when 0 is returned.